# Sort Rails Serializer Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I have this serializer

```
class SuperCoolClassSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :foo, :bar, :price
end
```

How would I sort the data/json to be returned back, ascending by price

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the data is sorted before serializing it.

So, you could do in the model a scope that sorts it as you wish.  Then, in your controller, you'd just use that scope and it should serialize the data as it's received.

[Here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html) is some documentation on scopes, if you're unfamiliar.